# Add product ID as a sufix in product title for Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add product ID as a suffix in the product title for example:

iPhoneX - 123  (where 123 is the ID)

The reason why I need this is something related to the payment gateway I am dealing with. hence, this solution only needs to be applied where it is necessary for the payment gateway to recognize that ID during checkout.

The following code shows product ID as a suffix on checkout the way I wanted. however, When placing the order and redirecting to the third-party payment gateway page; the ID does not show there. I want the third-party payment gateway to display it as well.

```
add_filter('the_title', 'change_woocommerce_single_title', 1, 2);

function change_woocommerce_single_title($title, $id) {

if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) && is_checkout())
  $title = $title . ' - ' . $id;
  
return $title;
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Comment: in single page or everywhere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing <title> in Woocommerce page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494520/changing-title-in-woocommerce-page)

Comment: @RajkumarSharma, Initially I want it where it will be shown when redirecting to a third-party payment gateway. So I am guessing on checkout that will work. If it will require showing everywhere including the back-end then won't be a problem.

Comment: @jiali Edited the question for better clarification with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// For shop
function change_woocommerce_single_title($title, $id) {

    if ( in_array( get_post_type( $id ), array( 'product', 'product_variation') ) || is_product() )
      $title = $title . ' - ' . $id;
      
    return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'change_woocommerce_single_title', 1, 2);

// For cart
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) { 
    
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] )
        $id = absint( $cart_item['variation_id'] );
    else
        $id = absint( $cart_item['product_id'] );
        
    $item_name = $item_name . ' - ' . $id;

    return $item_name;
    
}; 
         
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_name', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function to handle the product title. Put this code to `function.php` of your child theme:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'change_woocommerce_single_title', 1, 2);

function change_woocommerce_single_title($title, $id) {

   if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) && is_product())
      $title = $title . ' - ' . $id;
      
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: That Showed ID of everything including navigation menu pages on a single product page.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. I just need to show the ID of a product as a suffix of its title. I want it to be shown where third-party payment gateway will also recognize that ID in the product title.  Its a bit complex I know lol

Comment: I managed to make it show on checkout by replacing is_product with is_checkout. however, the payment gateway does not recognize the ID when redirecting after placing the order. I guess this change has to be applied globally for that to work? any advice will be appreciated